# Error while inserting record in table of sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting data from the other table using webservices.I am tracing each value of the table so i am sure that i am getting values but i am unable to insert them into my new table.I am not able to get where i went would any one help me out..

The code i am using for this is

```
         private void insertData(String bbookId,String bdesc, byte[] image1,byte[] image2 ,String bid,String bname) {
            Log.i("id",bid);
            Log.i("BookId",bbookId);
            Log.i("name",bname);
            System.err.println("url1"+image1);
            System.err.println("url2"+image2);
            System.err.println("desc"+bdesc);
            Log.e("testing","LOOK @ 1214353469TRJB UJIOY ");
             SQLiteDatabase db = placeData.getWritableDatabase();
             Log.i("Bookid",bbookId);
             ContentValues values;
             values = new ContentValues();
             values.put("bbookid",bbookId);
             values.put("desc",bdesc);
             values.put("url1",image1);
             values.put("url2",image2);

             values.put("bid",bid);
             values.put("name", bname);
             Log.i("inserting","______________");
              db.insert("pagess", null, values); 
        }
```

I am getting all the log values successfully and the log tag "inserting" **_** is also being displayed

My database class is ::::::::

```
   public class PlaceData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "page.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "pagess";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String KEY_ID="bid";
private static final String KEY_BBOOKID="bbookid";
private static final String KEY_NAME="name";
private static final String KEY_URL1="url1";
private static final String KEY_URL2="url2";
private static final String KEY_DESC="desc";
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Context context;
public PlaceData(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.i("table","table");
    Log.i("bookid in table is ",KEY_BBOOKID);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE+"("+KEY_BBOOKID+" varchar(15),"+KEY_DESC+" text(1500),"+KEY_URL1+" BLOB,"+KEY_URL2+" BLOB,"+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"+KEY_NAME+" varchar(150))");   
}   
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
     boolean dbExist = checkDataBase(DATABASE_NAME);
     if(dbExist){
    Log.i("g","ds");         
     }else{
      CopyFiles();
     }
    }
    private void CopyFiles()
    {
     try
        {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
         File outfile = new File("data/data/com.books.bcukbook/databases/",DATABASE_NAME);
         outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
         outfile.createNewFile();

        if (is == null)
          throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        else
        {
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);      
         byte buf[] = new byte[128];
             do {
              int numread = is.read(buf);
                 if (numread <= 0)
                     break;
              out.write(buf, 0, numread);
               } while (true);

             is.close();
             out.close();
        }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }    
    public long insert(String bbookid, String desc,String url1,String url2,String bid,String name){

          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();      
          contentValues.put(KEY_BBOOKID,bbookid);
          contentValues.put(KEY_DESC,desc);
          contentValues.put(KEY_URL1,url1);
          contentValues.put(KEY_URL2,url2);
          contentValues.put(KEY_ID,bid);
          contentValues.put(KEY_NAME,name);
          return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
         }
    public Cursor selectQuery(String query) throws SQLException
    {
     String myPath = "data/data/com.books.bcukbook/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME;
     CursorFactory bcuk_pages = null;
     SQLiteDatabase myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, bcuk_pages, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
     Cursor mCursor =myData.rawQuery(query, null);
     mCursor.moveToFirst();    
        myData.close();
        return mCursor;
    }
private void versionUpdation(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}
public boolean checkDataBase(String db) {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
     File dbFile = new File( "data/data/com.books.bcukbook/databases/" +  DATABASE_NAME);  
       return dbFile.exists();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion >= newVersion)
        return;
    if (oldVersion == 1) {
        Log.d("New Version", "Datasadsggfdh can be upgraded");
    }
    Log.d("Sample Data", "onUpgrade : " + newVersion);
}
     @Override
     public synchronized void close() {
           super.close();
     }

    }
```

My Log shows as

```
  12-10 14:13:41.285: I/inserting(30596): ______________
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596): Error inserting bbookid=1 desc=<p>Providing in-depth coverage of how to build mobile applications using the next major release of the Android SDK, this invaluable resource takes a hands-on approach to discussing Android with a series of projects, each of which introduces a new feature and highlights techniques and best practices to get the most out of Android.</p> url1=[B@42725768 bid=2 url2=[B@42636730 name=Hello World page1
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at com.books.bcukbook.DetailsActivity$LoadAllProducts.insertData(DetailsActivity.java:688)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at com.books.bcukbook.DetailsActivity$LoadAllProducts.callInsertion(DetailsActivity.java:663)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at com.books.bcukbook.DetailsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(DetailsActivity.java:616)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at com.books.bcukbook.DetailsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(DetailsActivity.java:1)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  12-10 14:13:41.295: E/SQLiteDatabase(30596):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

`values.put("bid",bid);`  From insert Statement values.

As `bid` is **Auto Increment Primary Key**.

And try again..

**Update:**

From your `PlaceData Database class`.

```
KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

And `private static final String KEY_ID="bid";`

So you don't have to insert `bid` Primary Key. Your Sqlite Table automatically generates (increment) it. For every New inserted Record.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not try to put value of bid because it is already auto increment value.**

Remove this **values.put("bid",bid);**

No need to insert it, it violates primary key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

log tells you whats wrong! your insert terminate your primary key constraint.check for inserting repeated value to primary key field

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error itself tells you exactly whats wrong:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be
>   unique (code 19)

You don't really need to provide `KEY_ID` value.

Comment: Doesn't matter. `bid` is a Primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

You created table with one `Primary Key`. So its value must be `unique` and not `NULL`. So it works fine when you are running at first time. But Second time it is taking same value so its not meets constraints requirements.